# How to remove laravelnews/laravel-twbs4 and add latest version of Bootstrap 4 while upgrading to Laravel 5.6 from 5.5

Tags: composer-php, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have Laravel 5.5 installed and laravelnews/laravel-twbs4 version 1.1.

I am upgrading to Laravel 5.6. It's throwing an error when I executed the `composer update` command:

```
 Problem 1
    - laravelnews/laravel-twbs4 1.3.2 requires laravel/framework ~5.5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.38, v5.5.39, v5.5.4, v5.5.40, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

So should I uninstall laravelnews/laravel-twbs4 and then upgrade to 5.6 and use the Bootstrap preset or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [laravelnews/laravel-twbs4](https://github.com/laravelnews/laravel-twbs4) GitHub project where it says it's only for Laravel 5.5.

> Laravel 5.6 includes Bootstrap 4, this preset is for Laravel 5.5 LTS

If you want to upgrade to 5.6 you should uninstall the package, following:

1. Remove the package from vendor, composer.json and composer.lock: `composer remove laravelnews/laravel-twbs4`
2. Do a `composer update` to apply the changes.
3. Remove the service provider + aliases from `app/config/app.php`
4. Make sure you don't have references from the package in your code.

Then you can keep upgrading your Laravel 5.5 to Laravel 5.6.